# =importxml string Google Sheets- Alexa Audience

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, alexa-internet

I am trying to scrape the audience figures out of Alexa through =importxml but can't get the query to work.

So far I have

```
=importxml(B3,"//section[@id='visitors-content']")
```

B3 refers to the cell with the url... I am returning N/A not an error so I think I am close!

If anyone can see what I am doing wrong I would be grateful, very new to this.

Comment: can you share the url your querying so we can test it and give u an answer or at least tell us what specifically your trying to pull out because that xpath looks like it points to the map portion but you have not explained which data you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

had similar issues with HTML5 sections

From my opinion GDoc does not support this kind of query. Same Formula works in Excel: I would reccomend SEO TOOLs by Niels Bosma for XPATH Querys (for Excel, no iOS Support).

Best Adrian